# how do I design my authenticated requests and my frontend

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, keycloak, svelte

i am currently working on a project where my backend uses Spring Boot, Spring security + keycloak and runs on localhost:8081.

My frontend (svelte) runs on http://127.0.0.1:5173/ and the url http://127.0.0.1:5173/products  needs to access data from localhost:8081/products (which needs a login) but the login page from keycloak doesnt appear.

In other words, what i am trying to achieve:
I want that the url http://127.0.0.1:5173/products redirects to localhost:8081/products which redirects to keycloak login page and after a successfull login i want to return to http://127.0.0.1:5173/products where i will be able to see the data.

is there an elegant solution to this problem? Im really stuck on this problem and this is one of my first projects.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some OAuth2 wording:

- Keycloak is an authorization-server (OIDC complient)
- Svelte app is a client
- Spring REST API is a resource-server

#### Svelte app configuration

The same two options for securing a Svelte app, as for any other Javascript based web app (Angular, React, Vue, etc.):

- the "old" way with:

  - a "public" client is declared in Keycloak
  - Svelte app configured as an OAuth2 public client with an existing OIDC lib (component) of your choice to:

    - use the "public" client deckared in Keycloak
    - authenticate users against Keycloak (socket is not the same as spring API)
    - add an authorization header with a JWT access-token retrieved from Keycloak (when issuing requests to your secured REST endpoints)
- the now recommended way: apply the BFF pattern. With a Backend For Frontend, web apps are secured with sessions (and CSRF tokens) on a middleware on the server. This middleware is in charge of acquiring and storing OAuth2 tokens. It then replaces the session cookie with a Bearer Authorization header containing an access token before forwarding a request from the web app to resource server(s). `spring-cloud-gateway` can be configured as BFF (`TokenRelay` filter and Spring OAuth2 client conf with `oauth2Login`). I have written a [tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).

#### REST API

Configure Spring API as a secured resource-server with a JWT decoder.

I have written a [set of tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for configuring Keycloak and Spring apps with OAuth2.

Comment: 1) you can configure WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with JWT decoder; 2) the configuration from the article works with 2.7.x; 3) yes, you can use access-token introspection (opaque token in spring-security wording) instead of JWT decoding but it is far less efficient; 4) read ALL the article (including the intro on OAuth2), you need it, apparently

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I was able to secure my requests using this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak

Can you maybe take a look at it and tell me if I can build on it to solve my problem?

Comment: You can't be serious :/ This article you link is building a Spring **client** with Thymeleaf (depending on spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client). Follow [the link in the answer](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers), **read it carefully** to configure your Spring API as a **resource-server**, find a Svelte client lib for OIDC and **read its doc carefully too**.